# Find the number of substrings of a String that contain some anagram of another String as a subsequence

Tags: string, algorithm, subsequence

We have to find number of substrings of a String that contain some anagram of another String as a subsequence.

The substrings are considered different only if there start or end positions differ.

```
String="aba"
anotherString="a"

Occurence of "a" in "aba" is as follows :

a     at index 0..0
ab    at index 0..1
aba   at index 0..2
ba    at index 1..2
a     at index 2..2

i.e total of 5 times...so o/p=5
(the start and end points here, are inclusive)
```

I thought this question as one of the application of "number of occurrences of a subsequence in a string" and "Find the smallest window in a string containing all characters of another string".

But even after many changes in the combined code I am unable to come up with the solution .
Pasting my code is of no use as I know where I am wrong .what I want to know is how can we solve this efficiently without brute force solution.

Code :

```
public static void findLengthAndSequence(String str1,String str2){

    int begin=0,biginWith=0,endWith=0,count=0,minLen=Integer.MAX_VALUE,len=0;
    int l=0;

    int [] hasFound=new int[256];
    int [] toFound=new int[256];

    for(int i=0;i<str2.length();++i){           
        toFound[(int)str2.charAt(i)]++;
    }

    for(int end=0;end<str1.length();++end){
        if(toFound[(int)str1.charAt(end)]==0)
            continue;
        hasFound[(int)str1.charAt(end)]++;
        if(hasFound[(int)str1.charAt(end)]<=toFound[(int)str1.charAt(end)]){
            count++;
        }

        if(count==str2.length()){
            l++;        //add this to find number of such anagram in string
            System.out.println("l= "+l+" "+begin+" "+end); 
            while(toFound[(int)str1.charAt(begin)]==0 || hasFound[(int)str1.charAt(begin)]>toFound[(int)str1.charAt(begin)]  )
            {
                if(hasFound[(int)str1.charAt(begin)]>toFound[(int)str1.charAt(begin)]){
                    hasFound[(int)str1.charAt(begin)]-=1;                       
                }
                begin++;
            }//while
        len=end-begin+1;
        if(minLen>len){
            minLen=len;
            endWith=end;
            biginWith=begin;
        }
    }//if   
    }//end

    for(int i=biginWith;i<=endWith;++i){
        System.out.print(""+str1.charAt(i));
    }
}
```

This code gives output =3 to above question. 
I know I am not able to check every substring in this once I traversed remaining substrings once I reach end of first string.

```
e.g in "aba" my code checks for a,ab,aba.but once I reach the end it will not check   
ba,a .since we need to count this also as they are having different index values.
```

Is there any way other than brute force of exponential time complexity to check for every possible substring..

Comment: Checking all substrings is not exponential. There are exactly `n * (n - 1) / 2` substrings in a string of length `n`. It is obviously a polynomial.

Comment: So what time complexity do you want to achieve?

Comment: @ILoveCoding that was a mistake..thanks..but there are additional cost associated with each substring check of O(MN)...I think we can't get better than O(MN) where M and N are string lengths.Do you have any algo  for this question dude ?

Answer (score 5):

Here is a simple solution with `O(n + m)` time complexity(I assume that alphabet size is a constant(where `n` is the length the first string(the one we want to count substrings in) and `m` is the length of the second string(the anagram string)). I will call a substring that contains an anagram of the second string "good".

1. Let's define `count(x, y)` as the number of occurrences of a `y` character in a string `x`. Then an arbitrary string `s` contains an anagram of a string `t` as a subsequence if and only if `count(s, c) >= count(t, c)` for all `c`(the proof is simple so I will omit it).
2. Let's define `firstRight(L)` as the smallest `R` such that a `[L, R]` substring is a good one(it is possible that there is no such `R`). Then `firstRight(L) <= firstRight(L + 1)` for all valid `L`(because of the 1. and the properties of the `count(x, y)` function).
3. The statment 1. implies that any string can be represented as a vector with `alphabetSize` elements, where the `i`-th element of this vector is the number of occurrences of the character `i`. The statement 2. implies that we can use two pointers.
4. So a pseudo code of this algorithm looks like this:

   ```
   def getCharacterVector(string s):
       result = a vector filled with zeros
       for c in s
           result[c]++
       return result

   // Checks that all elements of the first vector
   // are greater than or equal to the corresponding
   // elements of the second vector
   def isGreaterOrEqual(first, second)
       for i = 0 ... length(first)
           if first[i] < second[i]
               return false
       return true

   def countSubstrings(string s, string t)
       vT = getCharacterVector(t)
       vS = a vector filled with zeros
       right = 0
       // computes firstRight(0)
       while (right < length(s) and not isGreaterOrEqual(vS, vT))
           vS[s[right]]++
           right++
       if not isGreaterOrEqual(vS, vT) // firstRight(0) is undefined
           return 0 // there are no such substrings
       res = length(s) - right + 1
       for left = 1 ... length(s) - 1
           vS[s[left - 1]]--
           // computes firstRight(left)
           while right < length(s) and vS[s[left - 1]] < vT[s[left - 1]]
               vS[s[right]]++
               right++
           if vS[s[left - 1]] < vT[s[left - 1]] // firstRight(left) is undefined
               break // we are done
            res += length(s) - right + 1
       return res
   ```

   The idea here is two compute the number of good substrings that start in a fixed position and end anywhere and use two pointers two adjust the right border efficiently. The time complexity of this implementation is `O(N * ALPHABET_SIZE + M)`(which is `O(N + M)` if we treat the alphabet size as a constant), but is actually possible to do the `firstRight(0)` computation more efficient by keeping track of the "bad" positions in `vS` and `vT` vector and represent this vectors as hash tables to achieve `O(N + M)` the complexity regardless of the alphabet size.

Comment: Looks good - another way to make this linear time is in firstRight(0) computation to keep track of how many matches have been found.  When vS[s[right]] becomes equal to vT[s[right]] for the first time you can increment the number of matches by vS[s[right]].  The loop can stop once matches becomes equal to length(t).